# How to save windows cmd output to a textfile?

Tags: windows, cmd, ping

I have a cmd command to ping to a specific address every 10 seconds, when it success it will display the reply statistic and when it fails it will echo "RTO" on the cmd output.

```
for /L %i in (1,0,2) do @ping -n 1 192.168.20.254 | FIND "TTL=" || echo RTO & ping -n 10 127.0.0.1 > NUL 2>&1
```

it works perfectly on the CMD output... but I want its output to be saved automatically to a text file. how can i do that?

thanks!

Comment: `c:\>ping www.google.com > C:\temp\pingresults.txt`

Comment: if i add another "> C:\output dir" on my command above, it's not working

Comment: What exactly are you trying to write to the file?

Comment: Your command above makes no sense. For example you set %i and then never use it ...

Answer (score 1):

```
@(for /L %i in (0) do @((ping -n 1 192.168.20.254 | FIND "TTL=" || echo RTO) & ping -n 10 127.0.0.1 > NUL 2>&1)) > file.txt
```

As indicated in the rest of answers, you need to add a redirection in your command. But just appending it at the end will not make it work, as you will only trying to redirect the yet redirected wait ping. You need to enclose the full command in parenthesis to redirect the output of the full group

Answer (score 0):

command > file
  Redirects output of a command to a file
command >> file
  Appends the output of a command to a file

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will be helpful for you :
http://pcsupport.about.com/od/commandlinereference/a/redirect-command-output-to-file.htm

Comment: for /L %i in (1,0,2) do @ping -n 1 192.168.20.254 | FIND "TTL=" || echo RTO & ping -n 10 127.0.0.1 > NUL 2>&1 > "C:\Users\yourUser\Desktop\test.txt"